# Javascript: Non Linear Range Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rangeslider

I have built this range slider, but would like to make it behave differently. I want to know if it is possible to make the value of the slider handle be 1,000 when it gets to the center of the slider, and when at the right end it should be 10,000.

Below is the code I have so far:

```js
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
    polyfill: false,
    onSlide: function (pos, val) {
      $('input[type="text"]').val(val)
    },
    onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {
      
      const sliderValue = value;
      
      if (value >= 1000) {
        const upperLimit = Math.ceil(value/100) * 100
        const lowerLimit = Math.floor(value/100) * 100
        
        const upperWeight = Math.abs( upperLimit - value)
        const lowerWeight = Math.abs( value - lowerLimit)
        
        value = upperLimit
        
        if (upperWeight > lowerWeight) {
          value = lowerLimit
        }
      }
      
      if (value >= 10000) {
        value = 10000
      }
      
        $('input[type="range"]').val(value).change()
    },
});


$('input[type="text"]').on('blur', function (e) {
  $('input[type="range"]').val($(this).val()).change()
})
```

```css
  
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  
 
}

 input[type="text"] {
   margin-top: 50px;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
   border-radius: 5px;
   font-size: 25px;
   color: #444;
   padding: 5px  25px;
   outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.2/rangeslider.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input
      type="range"
      min="100"            
      max="10000"          
      step="10"           
      value="1000"
  />
  
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

The below image shows an illustration of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest looking at https://codepen.io/martinAnsty/pen/BCotE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to [find an exponential function](https://sciencing.com/exponential-equation-two-points-8117999.html) on your *x-axis* (from 0 to 100) that has the required output on *y-axis* (from 100 to 10000).

Then, you adjust your `input` for your *x* values, and calculate the *y* wherever you use the output.

```js
const x = document.getElementById('input');
const y = document.getElementById('output');

const a = 100;
const b = Math.pow(a, 1/a);

function updateOutput(event) {
  y.innerText = Math.floor(a * Math.pow(b, x.value));
}
updateOutput();
input.addEventListener('mousemove', updateOutput);
```

```html
<input
  id="input"
  type="range"
  min="0"            
  max="100"    
  value="0"
  step="1"
/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: This is beautiful

Comment: This is actually perfect, in this case the 50% mark maps perfectly to the value we desire, what happens when it doesn't map exactly?

Comment: To rephrase the question, I have an input box in mine, which should allow the user manually enter the value of the slider, I was able to get the formula for the reverse operation, but there are certain values it can't accept because the formula is not linear

Comment: If I understand you, you have an input box where the user can enter a value (an output value from 100 to 10000) and you want to move the slide to the corresponding input. In that case, you should calculate the inverse of your exponential function.

Answer (score 1):

You need **exponential** function specious. Reading my answer is not necessary.

Please read my comment below your question. This answer will be complete beside it.

---

**tip:** in this sample we have a linear func with two parts. you can change it as you want.

```
var SliderWidth=1000, perUnit = SliderWidth/2000/*constant*/;

function y(currPos){
    return currPos<=SliderWidth/2?currPos/perUnit:(currPos/perUnit)*10;
}
```

now in your event:

```
onSlide: function (pos, val) {
    $('input[type="text"]').val(y(val))
}
```

now you can replace y with any function (exponential function or etc...).

Comment: Thank you Hassan, but I don't think I quite understand

Comment: you'r welcome; check update please. i hope this help. this answer is base on a simple function that combines two linear funcs.